# Thymeleaf: th:text only if not null?

Tags: jsp, thymeleaf, template-engine

I have something like below, which of course works if user had previously input his wrong credentials.

However if I directly go to my login fail url `/login?error` for example without any previous incorrect logins, `session[SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION]` is of course `null` and I get a nasty **404**.

```
<span th:text="${session[SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION].message}">Invalid credentials</span>
```

**Question**:

Is there a processor for something like below (which is too long to write and read most of the time), or should I just roll my own?

```
<span th:text="${session[SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION] != null ? session[SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION].message : #messages.msg('AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials')}">
    Invalid credentials
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the th:if statement:

```
<span th:if="${session[SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION].message}" th:text="${session[SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION].message}">Invalid credentials</span>
```

That will only display this line if there is a value present.

EDIT 1:

Extra check:

```
<span th:if="${session[SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION] != null and session[SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION].message != null}" th:text="${session[SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION].message}">Invalid credentials</span>
```

Comment: if `session[SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION]` is null, it will throw a n `NPE` on `.message`

Comment: Not the case, if it is null then if statement is FALSE therefore th:text doesn't get rendered.

Comment: This is what you wrote `th:if="${session[SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION].message}"`

Comment: I've edited the answer to add another layer of tests just in case it doesn't work for you (which it did for me for a similar thing).

Answer (score 3):

Try this code, it is more optimal:

```
${session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION']?.message}
```

? - checks if the resource is not null

Comment: This works and is nicely succinct! Is it documented anywhere? I don't see it in thymeleaf's docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<span th:if="${session[SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION].message != null}">
    <span th:text="${session[SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION].message}">Invalid credentials</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller set the null string variable as

```
String nullvalue="";
model.addAttribute("nullvalue",nullvalue);
model.addAttribute("entity",entity);
```

then in your view class as in thymeleaf

```
<td data-th-if="${entity.field != nullvalue}">ok</td>
```